# Can single Solr server handle large data?

Tags: solr, solrj

I have used Solr (version 7.1.0) for searching purpose. For small amount of data, it is working fine. Now I want to index **100 GB data** (4 000 000 000  documents) into it. Each document has only 3 fields** (two string fields and one integer field). I can keep all documents into **5 separate solr cores**. I am facing some problem during document ingestion, so I need some estimation.

1. Can anyone give me the minimum limit of hardware resources for this purpose?
2. Are there any problem using single solr server with 100 GB data (with 5 number of cores) ?
3. Can solr server answers the queries in an acceptable time ?
4. Is there an upper limit for index size ?

I am using SolrJ for the purpose of querying to Solr. Using `http post` I am ingesting 50 000 document at a time through a .csv file.

Answer (score 1):

1. The minimum requirements will depend on completely different things than the number of documents, and are usually more a consequence of how and how fast you want to use the data (i.e. what your requirements are when it comes to response times and what kind of functionality you expect to use across the data).
2. No
3. No
4. Yes, (at least previously) lucene ids are signed ints, so a single index were limited to 2^31-1 documents. You can work around this limitation by sharding your index across multiple Solr instances, even if the shards were located on the same server. This also gives you more concurrency and better use of multiple cpus in the same computer.

Summed up - there is nothing in the information given that should be an issue.